# Calender Date Difference Calculation error in Android

Tags: android, date, calendar, datediff

I know there are many formats of example to calculate the two dates difference. I tried in a way from that one. My answer is always correct if I input the dates within a single month. If I go for finding difference more than a month it was not giving correct answer. It was always finding the difference for two dates. How can I find date difference more that 31 days or 2016-01-05 to 2015-12-13.

```
Date oldDate,newDate;
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;

//editText1=2015-12-13
//editText2=2016-01-05

oldDate = dateFormat.parse(editText1.getText().toString());
newDate = dateFormat.parse(editText2.getText().toString());
oldDate=dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(oldDate));
newDate=dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(newDate));
long diff = newDate1.getDate() - oldDate1.getDate();
editText3.setText(""+(diff+1));
```

Comment: It's obvious, because `getDate()` return a value which is between 1 and 31 representing the day of the month that contains or begins with the instant in time represented by this Date object, as interpreted in the local time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the dates to timestamps in milliseconds, subtract one from the other, and divide the result by 86400000 (milliseconds in a day).

```
long oldTime, newTime;
oldTime = dateFormat.parse(editText1.getText().toString()).getTime();
newTime = dateFormat.parse(editText2.getText().toString()).getTime();
long daysDiff = Math.abs(newTime - oldTime) / DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS;
```

Comment: This will usually fail by one day in time zones with day light saving where one date is in winter time and another date in summer time.

Comment: Thank you so much @karakuri